# How to apply css style on the list of div by defending on the class name using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got list of li tag that have 2 kinds of class name coding and design. The result that i want is if the li is design the post-link is display block and the site-link is display none while coding class name will have opposite effect. I store the li class into array then the condition will loop to find out what li tag have class name of design and coding. The result is the condition only read the last element of the array. Can you help me on this... sorry not good in asking question in english.

HTML

```
<li class="Design">
    <a class="post-link"></a>
    <a class="site-link"></a>
</li>
<li class="Design">
    <a class="post-link"></a>
    <a class="site-link"></a>
</li>
<li class="Coding">
    <a class="post-link"></a>
    <a class="site-link"></a>
</li>

var workArray = [];
var $work = jQuery('.slide-container li');
var $workClass = $work.attr('class');

$work.each(function(){
        workArray.push($workClass);
        for(i = 0; i < workArray.length; i++){
            if(jQuery(this).hasClass('Design')){
                jQuery('.post-link').css('display','block');
            }else{  
                jQuery('.post-link').css('display','none');     
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: In your very complicated snippet, you could pass context: `jQuery('.post-link', this).css('display','block');` or `$(this).find('.post-link').css('display','block');`. ***Side note:*** a class name shouldn't start with an uppercase letter

Comment: ↑↑↑ sorry i meant, a name referring to attribute class shouldn't start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css:

```
.Design .site-link {
   display: none;
}

.Coding .post-link {
   display: none;
}
```

and let the browser does the array/traverse push/pop by itself ;)

Comment: Sorry but im slow... i want to know what is the problem with my code... array only read the last element of the array...

Comment: why you do thing like that??? im curious to know why.. is there any scientific reason of this and not just a 'practical case' as you said in the beginning of your question?

Comment: Thanks for the help... maybe i just need some fresh air... already solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Just use relevant selectors and methods:

```
$('.Design .post-link').show(); // useless if not hidden by default
$('.Coding .post-link').hide();
```

Of course, you could just set CSS rules:

```
.Design .post-link { display: block;}
.Coding .post-link { display: none;}
```

It sounds like you are overcomplicating it.